# How to run rake task, not used cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby 1.8.7
I have a post.rake and how to run rake task every day?

1. solution add a script in cron:

   0 0 * * * /path/script.sh

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/.bashrc
cd /path/to/project
export RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake post:crontask -s
```

May have other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bad approach.  There are some popular Ruby gems that make things easier.  [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) are both popular.  They also work with Ruby 1.8.7, which isn't likely to be true of most alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
0 0 * * * cd /path/to/project && env RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake post:crontask -s
```